# How to set up a query to return phrases and parts of phrases in lucene.net?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I've got lucene.net running and I am having a little trouble with implementing a good approach to a query requirement that I have.

I'd like to be able to create a query that would enable the query to find hits on:

1) *"Sodium Bicarbonate"* - exact phrase query.

2) *"Sodi% Bicarb%"* - partial phrase query that at least has these letters.

3) *"sodium,**Sodium Bicarbonate**, sulfur"* - find exact phrase in a bigger phrase set with a form like 1) or 2).

This query will be applied to two fields in the document.
I've got the exact phrase query coded but need more flexibility. I have a standard analyzer that has a multifieldparser using a phrasequery object.

I can talk about this on a more conceptual level but would like to see some code samples, especially dealing with query construction.

thanks all

Comment: are you talking about SQL wild Cards for example `% %` used along with the `LIKE` Keyword...? do a google search on SQL Query `LIKE` statement examples

Comment: Yes, I thought that I would have to create booleanqueries to construct a set of the rules around the permutations that I am wanting. Not finding much about the sql query like equivalent.

Comment: are you familiar with `QBE` that means Query By Example you could write your own ISNULL() type of checking on the Database side I and I think that what you are trying to do would work using a LIKE '%' you probably would have to play around with the setting up 2 or 3 Like filters along with some If conditions

Comment: I am not using a relational db. I am using Mongo for one. Secondly, the nature of my question is specifically about querying the lucene document index. I just need to know what to use to create the proper query objects that I can run against the indexsearcher. This is all lucene specific. And I am familiar with QBE.

Comment: Are you willing to drop Lucene.NET altogether and use the full-blown [Lucene on IKVM](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FlexLucene/)? Your goal is achievable by combining `SpanNearQuery`, `SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper` and `WildcardQuery`, but `SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper` is unavailable in Lucene.NET.