# MultiFieldQueryParser and wildcards

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to set up lucene.net 3 to be able to search on two fields for a phrase and am getting stuck. Here is what I would like for the query to return:

I want the query to return exact phrase matches like:

phrase: "CHING WAN HUNG SOOTHING HERBAL BALM"

result: "CHING WAN HUNG SOOTHING HERBAL BALM"

As well as Wildcard matches:

phrase: "CHING WAN HUNG SOO" OR "CHING WAN HUN"

result: "CHING WAN HUNG SOOTHING HERBAL BALM" and others that might match this or any other incomplete variant of the phrase.

My initial solution was to create a boolean query with both a phrasequery and a query that parses and wildcards every word.

But this returns the match as well as too many results that are not close to being applicable. (It would return "HERBAL TEA" since "HERBAL" is one of the parsed terms...) Due to the parsed OR query.

This is related to an original post that I had : [How to set up a query to return phrases and parts of phrases in lucene.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851113/how-to-set-up-a-query-to-return-phrases-and-parts-of-phrases-in-lucene-net) Was wondering if I could do this in standard Lucene.net without resorting to the Java port mentioned.

Could someone give me any guidance about this? 
Thanks!

```
public override List<TT> ExecuteSearch(string searchQuery, string searchField = "")
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", ""))) return new List<TT>();

  using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(Directory, false))
  {
        var hits_limit = 1000;
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>());
        var fields = new[] {"CompositeName", "SubstanceName"};

        var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, fields, analyzer);
        parser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
        parser.PhraseSlop = 0;
        var query = ParseWholeQueryWc(searchQuery, fields, parser);
        searcher.SetDefaultFieldSortScoring(true, true);
        var hits = searcher.Search(query, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
        var results = MapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher);
        analyzer.Close();
        searcher.Dispose();
        return results;
  }
}

public Query ParseWholeQueryWc(string searchQuery, string[] fields, QueryParser parser)
{
  Query query = new PhraseQuery();
  Query query2 = new PhraseQuery();
  Query mq = new BooleanQuery();

  try
  {
        var bld = ParseTermWithWildcards(searchQuery);

        // phrase
        query = parser.Parse("\"" + searchQuery.Trim() + "\"");

        // or
        query2 = parser.Parse(searchQuery + "*");

        // main
        ((BooleanQuery)mq).Add(query, Occur.SHOULD);
        ((BooleanQuery)mq).Add(query2, Occur.SHOULD);
  }
  catch (ParseException ex)
  {
        throw;
  }
  return mq;
}
```

***UPDATE***

```
    public BooleanQuery ParseWholeQueryWc(string searchQuery, string[] fields, QueryParser parser)
    {
        BooleanQuery mq = new BooleanQuery();

        try
        {
            string[] qrArr = searchQuery.Split(null);
            SpanQuery[] compNmQ = new SpanQuery[qrArr.Length];
            SpanQuery[] subsNmQ = new SpanQuery[qrArr.Length];

            for (var i = 0; i < qrArr.Length; i++)
            {
                //CompositeName", "SubstanceName
                if (i == qrArr.Length - 1)
                {
                    compNmQ[i] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("CompositeName", qrArr[i] + "*"));
                    subsNmQ[i] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("SubstanceName", qrArr[i] + "*"));
                }
                else
                {
                    compNmQ[i] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("CompositeName", qrArr[i]));
                    subsNmQ[i] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("SubstanceName", qrArr[i]));
                }
            }

            SpanQuery compNameQ = new SpanNearQuery(compNmQ, 0, true);
            SpanQuery subsNameQ = new SpanNearQuery(subsNmQ, 0, true);

            // main
            ((BooleanQuery) mq).Add(compNameQ, Occur.SHOULD);
            ((BooleanQuery)mq).Add(subsNameQ, Occur.SHOULD);
        }
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("BaseLuceneStrategy:ParseWholeQueryWc():" + ex.Message);
        }
        return mq;
    }
```

This will now return zero hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have all the terms be required regardless of the order or proximity in which they appear, that's a simple fix.  Just add:

```
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
```

---

If all of your queries will start at the beginning of the field you wish to match, then you can change the field to a be unanalyzed.  If it isn't analyzed, then a simple wildcard query will do the job.  This will not be a good solution, however, if you want to be able to query for something like: `"HUNG SOOTHING HERBAL"`

---

Alternatively, SpanQueries to the rescue.  This is certainly nicer in Java, since in v3.1 we got `SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper` to work with, but in v3.0.3 (and thus the .Net port as well), you can make do with a `SpanRegexQuery`:

```
SpanQuery[] subqueries = new SpanQuery[4];
subqueries[0] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "CHING"));
subqueries[1] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "WAN"));
subqueries[2] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "HUNG"));
subqueries[3] = new SpanRegexQuery(new Term("field", "SOO.*"));
SpanQuery finalQuery = new SpanNearQuery(subqueries, 0, true)
```

Do the same for any other fields, and combine them in a `BooleanQuery`.

Comment: Thanks femtoRgon, I created this and it returns zero records now.

I added my modified code per your suggestion above in my original post.

Comment: Probably due to analysis.  Bear in mind, that analyzers won't be applied anywhere here.  Looks like you are using StandardAnalyzer, which lowercases everything, so you would need to lowercase your search terms.

Comment: I tolowered the string and it works well. Only thing is it gets zero hits when I try and search for "CHING WAN HUNG SOOTHING HERBAL BA" or "CHING WAN HUNG SOOTHING HERBAL BAL". Any idea why? Thanks again for replying.

Comment: OH! I forgot to include the wildcard. Just a sec ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting zero matches on the partial word BAL with a wildcard appended to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a SpanRegexQuery,  not SpanTermQuery for your wildcard,  and you must append `.*`

Comment: Made the changes to my code. This works great! Just what I needed!

Comment: Now I have another wrinkle in my search criteria. I have to be able to find phrases like "Dr. Whitiss (8.3%)". Currently, the way it is coded this will not return any hits. Same goes with 3-RAGWEED MIX. Any thoughts on what I may have to change?